# An olympiad problem in number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, contest-math

> Prove that there do not exist $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^2+y^2-8z=6$

My first thought is to write this equastion in the form $x^2+y^2=6 \pmod 8$ and examine all the possible pairs $(x,y) \in \{[0].[1]...[7]\} \times \{[0].[1]...[7]\}$ to see that there does not exist a pair which validates the above equation.

Is this attempt correct?

Also in case that my idea is correct,can someone propose a simpler solution for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the name "olympiad" suffers from inflationary usage ...

Comment: i found this problem in a greek book with contest math problems

Comment: It's fairly well known that $n^2 \equiv 0, 1, \mathrm{or}~4\pmod{8}$ for every integer $n$.

Comment: ... and if it's not known to you, it's easy enough to check.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Re: Inflationary usage: The problem is at a pre-university level of difficulty. Apparently any kind of competition involving people from  more than 1 country is an Olympiad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 6 \pmod 8,$ we know that both are odd. We can represent half this number using integers, namely
$$  \left( \frac{x+y}{2} \right)^2 +  \left( \frac{x-y}{2} \right)^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 4.   $$
This is impossible in integers.

In case this does not seem familiar, note that $u+v \equiv u - v \pmod 2,$ while
$$ (u-v)^2 + (u+v)^2 = 2 \left( u^2 + v^2 \right) $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=2n-1$ and $y=2m-1$.

We obtain that it's impossible!

Indeed, we get $n^2-n+m^2-m=2z+1$, which is contradiction.

Thus, $x$ and $y$ are even, which is contradiction again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..is my idea correct?

Comment: yes show that  with the remainders $0,1,4$ it is not possible to get $$x^2+y^2-6\equiv 0 \mod 8$$

Comment: @Ramiz Karaeski I think we can end the proof by your way, but it's a lot of work.

Comment: yes you are right ..with your solution i can avoid many cases to check..thanks again

Comment: @Ramiz Karaeski Welcome!

Comment: This solution does not eliminate the case $x$ even, $y$ odd (or vice versa).

Comment: @Daniel Schepler If so then an odd number equal to an even number, which is impossible.

Comment: @Michael i don't see how your proof covers the case of $x$ and $y$ are both even. (I do see how $4n^2+4m^2 \not\equiv 6 \mod 8$)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes, it's an easy case to eliminate, but it should be mentioned in the solution.  Otherwise, it looks like you're incorrectly arguing that because $\lnot (odd(x) \wedge odd(y))$, you conclude $even(x) \wedge even(y)$.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler You are right of course. Take my solution like the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Write $$x^2+y^2 = 8z+6$$ Then clearly $2\mid x^2+y^2$ so $x,y$ are both even or both odd.

- If both are even then we have $$x^2+y^2\equiv 0 \pmod 4$$ while right side is $2$ mod $4$ which is impossible
- If both are odd then $x^2\equiv y^2\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ so $$x^2+y^2\equiv 2 \pmod 8$$ while right side is $-2$ mod $8$ which is again impossible.